# ATMEGA328P Arduino Uno: Adjusting the brightness of LED with AVR Programming

Tags: arduino, avr

```
int led_pin = 9;
int duty_cycle = 63; //in %
int freq_OC = 16000; //in Hz
int freq_clk = 16000000; //in Hz
int prescaler = 1;

void setup() {

  //setting the port B pin (D9) as output for OC1A to override the normal port functionality
  DDRB = DDRB|(1 << led_pin);

  //clearing the counter/timer registers
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;

  //setting the prescaler 1
  TCCR1B = TCCR1B|(1 << CS10);

  //setting the mode 14 fast PWM
  TCCR1B = TCCR1B|((1 << WGM13)|(1 << WGM12));
  TCCR1A = TCCR1A|(1 << WGM11);

  //setting the fast PWM in non-inverting mode
  TCCR1A = TCCR1A|(1 << COM1A1);

  ICR1 = (freq_clk/(freq_OC*prescaler)) - 1;
  OCR1A = ICR1/(100/duty_cycle);
  
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

Why doesn't this code work when pin D9 is initialised as an output pin OC1A as written above? But it works when...

```
DDRB = DDRB|(1 << PB1);
```

Is there any reason for this? As far as the datasheet for ATMEGA328P is concerned, it quotes "If one or both of the COM1X1:0 bits are written to one, the OC1X overrides the normal port functionality of the I/O pin it is connected to". So does that mean the PB1 (or D9) pin no longer functions as an I/O pin and therefore I cannot initialise it with a variable name?

Comment: If you want to use AVR ports, you cannot use Arduino pin numbers.
Or vice versa.  `1 << led_pin` is nonsense in your case.

Comment: I understand, but in some of the other examples I did, I was able to initialise the pin normally rather than accessing the port itself. But anyways thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

`DDRB` is an 8-bit register, it has no 9th bit in it.
You have `led_pin` variable set to 9, therefore operation `DDRB = DDRB|(1 << led_pin)` has no effect.

There is no *D9* pin on the ATmega328P. But looks like you're talking about Arduino board. You can google "Arduino UNO Pinout". E.g. [this](https://images.prismic.io/circuito/8e3a980f0f964cc539b4cbbba2654bb660db6f52_arduino-uno-pinout-diagram.png?auto=compress,format)

You can see D9 pin of the board is connected to PB1 pin of the MCU. Therefore you have to use `DDRB |= (1 << 1)` (use value 1, not 9)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I though we could work with both arduino pin numbers and AVR register bits interchangeably. But your explanation made it clear, that in AVR programming only register bits can be used to program the port pin.